# Update ACF fields on a frontend form?

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end

I have the form below to update posts in a custom post type. In my custom post type I have some ACF fields which I also need to be able to update, but unsure how. I can update my default WordPress fields and can call in the ACF field data into the field I want to edit, but doesn't update once I submit it.

The custom ACF field below is called 'developer' and, as you can see..

```
$developer = get_field('developer');
```

I'm able to call the field and output the data into...

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="postDeveloper"><?php _e('Post\'s Developer:', 'framework') ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="postDeveloper" id="postDeveloper" value="<?php echo $developer; ?>" class="required" />
</fieldset>
```

But when I pass that data into (the ACF field name is 'developer' as below)...

```
'developer' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postDeveloper'])),
```

It doesn't save the edit and update the post... I suppose there's something I'm not doing right, since I'm doing this the way I'd update the default WordPress fields, so just wondering if anyone has any idea how to do this?

All my code is below...

```
<?php get_header('paw-regular'); ?>

<?php $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'propertyawardwinners', 'posts_per_page' =>'-1', 'post_status' => 'any' ) ); ?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php

if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {

if ( $_GET['post'] == $post->ID )
{
$current_post = $post->ID;
$title = get_the_title();
$content = get_the_content();
$developer = get_field('developer');
}
}
?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php global $current_post; 

$post_information = array(
'ID' => $current_post,
'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postTitle'])),
'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postContent'])),
'developer' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postDeveloper'])),
'post_type' => 'propertyawardwinners',
'post_status' => 'pending',
);
$post_id = wp_update_post($post_information);
?>

<div class="main wrap">
<div class="ts-row cf">
<div class="col-8 main-content cf">
    <form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="postTitle"><?php _e('Post\'s Title:', 'framework') ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="required" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
           <label for="postDeveloper"><?php _e('Post\'s Developer:', 'framework') ?></label>
           <input type="text" name="postDeveloper" id="postDeveloper" value="<?php echo $developer; ?>" class="required" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>      
           <label for="postContent"><?php _e('Post\'s Content:', 'framework') ?></label>
           <textarea name="postContent" id="postContent" rows="8" cols="30"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
           <?php wp_nonce_field('post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field'); ?>
           <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
           <button type="submit" onclick="return redirect()"><?php _e('Update Post', 'framework') ?></button>
        </fieldset>
     </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Anyone able to help me out with this? :(

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [update_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) to save the content.